# Having trouble using NaN figure

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart, nan, stacked-chart

I am trying to make a percent stacked bar plot, with 5 bars. 2 bars have no data but they can not be excluded from the chart. I set this value NaN (because I need to calculate means later). In this case one of these 2 is the first entry in the list. This results in not showing the top part of the chart. What I don't understand is that when I switch the first and second, making the second entry NaN, there is no problem.

Code :
Here NaN is first, 3 is second, which does not work. Switching NaN and 3 does work (See images below)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import nan

#Data
goed1 = [nan,3,152,9, nan]

tot1 = [1,1,15,2,1]
total = [(i * 16 ) for i in tot1]

fout1 = np.zeros(5)

for i in range(len(goed1)):
    fout1[i] = total[i] - goed1[i]

data = {'Goed': goed1, 'Fout': fout1}


#Grafiek
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

r = [0,1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#naar percentage
totaal = [i + j for i,j in zip(df['Goed'], df['Fout'])]
goed = [i / j * 100 for i,j in zip(df['Goed'], totaal)]
fout = [i / j * 100 for i,j in zip(df['Fout'], totaal)]

#plot
width = 0.85
names = ('Asphalt cover','Special constructions','Gras revetments','Non-flood defensive elements','Stone revetments')

plt.bar(r, goed, color='#b5ffb9', edgecolor='white', width=width, label="Detected")
plt.bar(r, fout, bottom=goed, color='#f9bc86', edgecolor='white', width=width, label="Missed")

# Add a legend
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), ncol=1)
plt.title('Boezemkade')

# Custom x axis
plt.xticks(r, names, rotation = 20, horizontalalignment = 'right')

# Show graphic
plt.show()
```

If anybody knows how to fix this, help is appreciated.

Plots:

NaN first:
[image: NaN first]

NaN second:
[image: NaN second]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to an numpy array, then search where are the NaN and replace them by 0.

```
goed1 = np.array([nan,3,152,9, nan])

where_are_NaNs = np.isnan(goed1)
goed1[where_are_NaNs] = 0
```

It will result:

[image]